# ClusterMessageSerializer ClassNotFoundException in Akka 2.2.x remote in OSGI

Tags: java, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, serialization, akka-cluster

I developed my application using a remote actor. Now I'm trying to install the bundle into Felix but the problem is that it's requiring me a ClusterMessageSerializer class. 
I'm not using a cluster and my configuration is a simple remote actor.
Do you know why this issue and how can I solve it?

I've tried to import akka.cluster but then felix requires scalabuff, version between 1.2.0 and 1.3.0 which are not bundle.

This is my application.conf:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
 }
}
```

and this is the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.cluster.protobuf.ClusterMessageSerializer not found by com.typesafe.akka.osgi
```

Comment: Facing the same problem here, which version of akka are you using? Can you insert your build file in the question?

Comment: also running in to the same thing. seems to be something with using akka remoting but not having the cluster package included

Answer (score 0):

I added akka-cluster and it seemed to work. Not totally sure why tho- my service is talking over akka remoting to a cluster, so it may just be the form of serialization it uses....